# Accessing gridview in all pages in C#-ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview. I need to display that gridview in four pages. I dont want to write the code for gridview in all four pages. Please tell a good approach to do this?

Comment: create UserControl, that will incapsulate your grid.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new WebUserControl and place a GridView inside it.
2. Write the necessary code in the codebehind, like fetching data from database.
3. Register the userControl in the page you want to add.

> ```
> <%@ Register src="WebUserControl1.ascx" tagname="WebUserControl1" tagprefix="uc1" %>
> ```

1. Now add the user control in your page, either by drag and drop from solution window and write this code.

> < uc1:WebUserControl1 ID="WebUserControl11" runat="server" />

Answer (score 0):

You could place the GridView inside a reusable [user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx) (.ASCX) and then reference this control in all 4 pages.

Answer (score 0):

Make it as **Web User Control** and write all your logics there . Access it using its instances.

Please look at the following link for your reference.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt3k2fyw.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1)create a WebUserControl with a grid inside

2)open your aspx design and drag and drop the WebUserControl in your aspx page it automatically registered.

3) use this process when ever you want that grid.

use below link to create user controler...

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/jayendra/how-to-create-user-control-in-Asp-Net/